# Using md5 hash in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, md5

im new to VB.Net.

IN PHP i would :

```
$key = '3432j432jk4';
$mobile = '07854214512';
$final = md5($key . $mobile);
```

So $final variable is carrying the data.

How do i replicate this in VB.NET ?

I tried the following :

```
Dim key As String "3432j432jk4"
Dim mobile As String "07854214512"
Using md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()

Dim final As String = Getmd5Hash(md5Hash, mobile, key)
```

What is happening is that "Getmd5Hash" is underlined and the error is "Getmd5Hash is not declared, might be because of protection level"

Comment: It's in the Cryptographic namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen , i read through it and made an attempt, but i had no success

Comment: You've only implemented half the test example shown on that page.

Comment: yeah, i noticed now there is alot more. Wow , a simple thing like a md5 hash can take so many lines of code.